# Divs in normal flow overlapping

Tags: css, html

I'm attempting to position a series of `div`'s (which are dynamic in height) one after another so that they are the same width as their parent. My understanding is that this is what the normal flow should do, but instead they end up overlapping.

See http://www.euro-endo.nl/technologies.php

My html:

```
<div id="col">

<div id="thing">
    <div id="rimage">
    <div id="pic1"></div>
</div>
<div id="ltext">
    text1
</div>
</div>
<div id="thing">
    <div id="limage">
    <div id="pic2"></div>
</div>
<div id="rtext">
    text2
</div>

</div>
```

and the corresponding css is:

```
#col { 
    position: absolute; left: 20px; right: 50px; top:0; bottom:0px;
    width: auto;
    padding: 10px 20px 0px 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
} 
#thing {
    position: static; 
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    Margin: 20px;
} 


#ltext {
    position: absolute; left: 0px; right: 210px; top:0px; bottom:0px; 
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}

#rtext {
    position: absolute; right: 0px; left: 210px; top:0px; bottom:0px; 
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
} 

#rimage {
    position: absolute; right: 0px; top:0px; bottom:0px; 
    width: 210;
    height: auto;
}


#limage {
    position: absolute; left: 0px; top:0px; bottom:0px; 
    width: 210;
    height: auto;
}
```

(There are a couple more of the `id="thing"` `div`'s but I think this gives the gist of it.)

Answer (score 2):

One big problem for sure...

You cannot have multiple `<div>`'s sharing the same `id`.

`id` must be unique for each `<div>`.

As noted in comments, you would use classes to apply styles to multiple elements at once.

You also have them all set to `position:absolute;` with `top:0px;` which puts them all in the same place simultaneously.

---

Running your page through the W3C Validator would catch many issues such as the multiple `id`'s...

[http://validator.w3.org](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://www.euro-endo.nl/technologies.php&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0)

Answer (score 1):

Your divs are NOT in the normal flow when they are positioned absolutely. This is why the elements overlap. Absolute positioning will places them 'absolutely' with reference to the nearest positioned parent.

Note the other comments about unique id names.